# <datatag> for Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a search page and [`<datatag>`](http://www.html-5.com/tags/datalist-tag/index.html) tag seems to be a great addition. Unfortunately I can't make it work in Chrome (it works in Firefox) and most of my users use Chrome.

Does anyone know what is the Chrome way of auto-completing a search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Datalst landed in Chrome Canary](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/04/datalist-landed-in-Chrome-Canary)

So it will probably work in Chrome 20.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery UI Autocomplete plugin, easy to use, and very much effective :) [visit JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

If the `<datalist>` element isn't [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist) in the browser yet (which it appears is not the case for the current Chrome), then you will need to use one of the myriad of JavaScript/jQuery based autocomplete polyfills, like [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).